# Communication between Fragments without Using Interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I was trying to communicate between two fragments, but I'm just a beginner so I want to know if there is any solution not using `interface`....

If there are Fragment A, B, and their Activity:

1. Sending values from Fragment A to Activity
   (In here, Fragment A is a current state)
2. Sending values from Activity to Fragment B

I know direct communication between two fragments is almost impossible,
but I don't think that makes me to use an `interface`.

Also, is there any method to use like `putExtra()` for fragment? I only know using `Serializable`.

Comment: there are third party libs that can act as EventBus. if your interested check green robots eventbus. if you use rxjava there are lots of libs available that act as eventbus. the android docs recommends the interface way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Android deverlopers page: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface

Basically, you define an interface in your Fragment A, and let your Activity implement that Interface. Now you can call the interface method in your Fragment, and your Activity will receive the event. Now in your activity, you can call your second Fragment to update the textview with the received value

```
  // You Activity implements your interface
  public class YourActivity implements FragmentA.TextClicked{
@Override
public void sendText(String text){
    // Get Fragment B
    FraB frag = (FragB)
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_b);
    frag.updateText(text);
  }
}


// Fragment A defines an Interface, and calls the method when needed
public class FragA extends Fragment{

TextClicked mCallback;

public interface TextClicked{
    public void sendText(String text);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (TextClicked) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
            + " must implement TextClicked");
    }
}

public void someMethod(){
    mCallback.sendText("YOUR TEXT");
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mCallback = null; // => avoid leaking, thanks @Deepscorn
    super.onDetach();
    }
     }

    // Fragment B has a public method to do something with the text
 public class FragB extends Fragment{

public void updateText(String text){
    // Here you have it
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate between fragments directly by using EventBus - send ordinary or sticky events by one fragment and subscribe to that event in another one. 
If don't want message to be lost, use sticky events - it work as sticky Intent in Android. It will be around until it is removed by targer fragment or because another event is pending.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can transfer data between fragments using `bundle` like you do in Activity using `putExtra`

```
        Bundle = bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("key","value");
        bundle.putSerializable("serialzedKey",SerializedValue);
        FragmentTransaction fts = ((BaseActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fts.add(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment);
        fts.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
        fts.commit();
```

In other fragment you can retrieve data using `getArguments()`

```
 String key = getArguments().getString("key");
SerializedModel = getArguments().getSerializable("serialzedKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call a method from the parent activity class that calls a method from fragment B like `((YourActivity)getActivity()).callMethod(T yourData)`

Comment: But isn't 'getActivity' increases backstack?

Comment: There is no backstacking. Your activity is a container for your fragments so that it can be a medium via which you can transfer data. Of course you have to make sure your fragments are in a proper state while receiving data using for ex. isAdded()  method

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my Github repo on using interfaces to communicate between fragments.

This is just a really simple example but displays the key concepts.

https://github.com/stoddayy/FragmentInteractionExample